# Parallele execution of objects in QT

Tags: qt, parallel-processing, semaphore

I have a program in QT which create large amount of objects for making numerous request.
This number being potentialy very big a happen to have this error :

> GLib-ERROR **: Creating pipes for GWakeup: Trop de fichiers ouverts
>
> Trop de fichiers ouverts = Too many files opened (in french)

I wanted to limit the number of connection object (to like 10-20) by creating a QSemaphore, acquiring one before creating a new object and releasing it when destroying it.

What in fact happens is that when I try to acquire a semaphore of value 0, the program waits, and even the objects' code stops running, which leads to never realeasing the semaphore and to an infinite loop.

How comes the others objects don't continue executing ? How to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You would normally use a [thread pool](http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/qthreadpool.html), a very large number of requests are queued but only a set of them are running at once (the number of threads in the pool) when one finishes the next in the queue starts

Comment: My threads make asynchronous calls using QNetworkManager. If the object is deleted when the run function is finished how can I get the answer